# Running a long conditional on the wordpress loop to display certain posts

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'll try and keep this simple.

I need to write a conditional that allows the user to either have 3 posts from one CPT or 1 from each CPT displaying on the homepage.

I have 3 CPT's and 1 taxonomy in each one.
Each taxonomy has 3 terms -> homeone, hometwo, homethree

these will be what the user selects to make that post appear on the homepage.

display post in the first loop | homeone = first loop
display post in the second loop | hometwo = second loop
display post in the third loop | homethree = thirdloop

So far to achieve wanted result I've written this but am yet to debug or test it as my knowledge of php is still lacking.

http://pastebin.com/R9g38eRq

The website I'm working on the 3 images with text underneath are what I'm going to be changing

http://goo.gl/lLGI3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using WP_Query to fine tune the query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query rather than using if statements and outputting the default wordpress loop.